# How can I copy one specific prefab/gameobject and all it's dependencies to another project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I select with the mouse mark one gameobject in the Hierarchy then in the menu make: 
 Assets > Export Package... but it's selecting in the export window all the hierarchy objects and children and I want to copy to another project only one specific object not the whole hierarchy.

Comment: The Export Asset option?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportpackage.html just disable `include dependencies` or manually select what you want to export and what not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy simple elements without considering dependencies, just create a prefab and drag from one Project tab to another Project tab.

To copy elements considering the dependencies export as an asset package, it has options to handle the dependencies: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html